# MODX REVO доработка поиска

Tags: modx, поиск

Реализован поиск на simplesearch. Работает прекрасно не не могу найти где именно меняется слово **Поиск** на кнопке, вместо него мне надо fa icon поставить. Подскажите где копать если кто в курсе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Копать в коде.
Вот пример

```
<form action="/" method="get">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="16">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск..." name="search"/>
     <button class="search-menu serachBtn" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </button>
</form>
```